# OSRM 4.8 import planet-latest.osm.pbf 31G

Tags: import, performance, configuration, open-source-routing-machine

I use OSRM version 4.8.

My VM configuration:

- 16 CPU
- 64 RAM
- 150G SWAP
- 150G stxxl disk size
- 250G data directory
- 50G root

When I import Europe-latest (17Gb) file - it takes about 6 hours to start routing.

When I import Planet-latest (31Gb) file - it takes more than 4 days! And it is still on the preparing step. All disk activities are only on swap disk.

When I start extract step it uses all 16 CPUs. But the preparing step uses only 1 (ignoring '-t 16' option)

Is this the expected performance?

Comment: Solve the problem by using 120Gb RAM and osrm-backend 4.9.
extract-prepare-route takes about 8h

Answer (score 2):

> 64 RAM

Yes this is not enough. The process is using a lot of swap memory making the pre-processing extremely slow. This takes about 6 hours on sufficiently sized machine for the car profile that ships with OSRM.

We usually run this on r3.4xlarge instances on AWS (120GB of memory). Please remember memory usage heavily depends on the profile that you use to prepare the data. The foot profile for example can go above 120GB of memory usage.

Comment: Thank you for reply!   
We use self edited car profile for routing trucks.
 Did you apply any OS changes for import big files? Or default configuration?
Next time I will add more RAM..